# Assign an array and a scalar variable in the same line

Tags: bash

I have the following command in a bash script

```
 (( ${#trf[@]} == 34 )) && trf=()
```

I want to add `mgbt=0` only if the test is true in addition to `trf=()`, but how could I keep things within a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compound and scalar assignments can be combined in the same command.

```
(( ${#trf[@]} == 34 )) && trf=() mgbt=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Several options come to mind ...

apply `mgbt=0` if the test is true

```
(( ${#trf[@]} == 34 )) && trf=() && mgbt=0           # Arnaud's answer
(( ${#trf[@]} == 34 )) && { trf=(); mgbt=0; }        # space after '{' and before '}' required and ...
                                                     # ';' after last command (mgbt=0) required
if (( ${#trf[@]} == 34 )); then trf=(); mgbt=0; fi
```

apply `mgbt=0` regardless of the test result

```
(( ${#trf[@]} == 34 )) && trf=(); mgbt=0
{ (( ${#trf[@]} == 34 )) && trf=(); }; mgbt=0        # space after '{' and before '}' required and ...
                                                     # ';' after last command (trf=()) required
if (( ${#trf[@]} == 34 )); then trf=(); fi; mgbt=0
```